# Filter Data before Rendering Highcharts

Tags: mysql, highcharts

I have a Highcharts Gantt chart which is pulling parsed JSON data from a MySQL table.

The data spans 4 years, but I need to filter it so that it only shows data for 2022.

The issue is that I cannot use the standard Highcharts data filter as it does not remove empty rows without any data.

I would like to filter the data before the chart is even rendered so that rows without bars are not shown at all. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy, you just need to filter your JSON data before creating a chart. A simplified process will be like below:

```
const receivedData = [{
    name: 'Start prototype',
    start: '2021-04-11',
    end: '2021-04-17'
}, {
    name: 'Test prototype',
    start: '2022-04-11',
    end: '2022-04-17'
}, {
    name: 'Develop',
    start: '2022-06-11',
    end: '2022-07-11'
}, {
    name: 'Run acceptance tests',
    start: '2022-09-11',
    end: '2022-09-21'
}];

const filteredData = receivedData.filter(
    dataEl => new Date(dataEl.start) > new Date('2022')
);

// THE CHART
Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
    series: [{
        name: 'Project 1',
        data: filteredData.map(({
            name,
            start,
            end
        }) => ({
            name,
            start: new Date(start).getTime(),
            end: new Date(end).getTime()
        }))
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0vhdg5jw/